# Why I can't bind static property with notification in .net core?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core

These days I need to bind a static property in .Net5. I followed the tutorial in http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties to achieve this.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.ResultText}}"></TextBlock>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click">Add</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static string _ResultText = "0";
        public static string ResultText
        {
            get => _ResultText; set
            {
                _ResultText = value;
                NotifyStaticPropertyChanged("ResultText");
            }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(_ResultText)+1;
            ResultText = i.ToString() ;
        }
        public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
        private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (StaticPropertyChanged != null)
                StaticPropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

After the program ran, in spite of the value changed, the UI doesn't change any.

What's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding syntax is wrong. If you use the correct syntax, shown in the article you are referencing, it works fine:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:MainWindow.ResultText)}"/>
```